# Nodemailer crashes when sending bigger image in base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, nodemailer

I want to embed a qrcode into email. This is the code which I am using right now to add a attachment:

```
mailOptions.attachments = [{
    filename: 'image.png',
    content: url.split("base64,")[1],
    encoding: 'base64'
}];
```

It works if the url is equal to:

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgAQMAAADYVuV7AAAABlBMVEUAAAAAAAClZ7nPAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAB9JREFUeAFjgIJRwP+BZM4oh/8/GHygIYd8h45yRgEAaHBnmaA4EHkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
```

However, when I change it to qrcode:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHQAAAB0CAYAAABUmhYnAAAAAklEQVR4AewaftIAAAKsSURBVO3BQW7kQAwEwSxC//9yro88NSBIM2sTjIg/WGMUa5RijVKsUYo1SrFGKdYoxRqlWKMUa5RijVKsUYo1SrFGKdYoxRrl4qEkfJNKl4QTlS4JncpJEr5J5YlijVKsUYo1ysXLVN6UhDtUuiS8SeVNSXhTsUYp1ijFGuXiw5Jwh8oTSehUuiS8KQl3qHxSsUYp1ijFGuXij1M5ScJJEjqVv6xYoxRrlGKNcvHHJeFE5SQJkxRrlGKNUqxRLj5M5ZNU7kjCm1R+k2KNUqxRijXKxcuS8E1J6FS6JHQqXRLuSMJvVqxRijVKsUaJPxgkCZ1Kl4QTlb+sWKMUa5RijXLxUBI6lZMk/E8qXRK6JHQqJ0noVLok3KHyRLFGKdYoxRrl4j9TeSIJncoTKl0STlTuUPmkYo1SrFGKNcrFQypdEt6UhCeS0Kl0KneonCThjiR0Kk8Ua5RijVKsUeIPXpSEE5WTJHQqJ0l4QqVLQqdykoROpUvCicqbijVKsUYp1igXH6bSJeFEpUtCp9KpdEk4UXkiCSdJ6FS6JHxSsUYp1ijFGiX+4A9LQqdyRxI6lTuS0Kl0SbhD5YlijVKsUYo1ysVDSfgmlZMknKjckYQ7knCi8knFGqVYoxRrlIuXqbwpCU+odEk4ScI3JaFTeaJYoxRrlGKNcvFhSbhD5X9SOUlCp9IloVPpktCpvKlYoxRrlGKNcjGMSpeEE5UuCScqJyonKp9UrFGKNUqxRrn441S6JNyRhBOVkyR0Kl0S7lB5olijFGuUYo1y8WEq36TSJeEOlS4JnUqn8psUa5RijVKsUS5eloRvSkKn0qm8KQknKp3KNxVrlGKNUqxR4g/WGMUapVijFGuUYo1SrFGKNUqxRinWKMUapVijFGuUYo1SrFGKNUqxRvkHv7QE9MppxbsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

the code is crushing and gives me the following error:

```
Error: Connection closed
at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\nodemailer-smtp-transport\lib\smtp-transport.js:113:29)
...
```

I believe it is caused by the fact that the qrcode is bigger, then the first image, however, it is still relatively small. I tried many ways but nothing gives me positive results. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Go to [..\node_modules\nodemailer-smtp-transport\lib\smtp-transport.js](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer-smtp-transport/blob/master/lib/smtp-transport.js#L100) and add to line 100 `console.error(err);`. So you will have the error description to next investigation.

Comment: I've done it, but it seems that it never actually calls that function.

Comment: Yeah... try to do add the same on line 127. Do you process errors in your code?

Comment: @AikonMogwai it doesn't enter line 127 neither

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are accessing images from physical location than use this code

```
var mailOptions = {
attachments: [{'filename': 'image.png','path': '\pathtoimagefile\image.png'}]
```

if you are generating qrcode from code than

```
    var qr_png = qr.imageSync('string', {
                    type: 'png'
                })
    var mailOptions = {
    attachments: [{'filename': 'image.png', 'content': qr_png}]
```

This code works for me

**Note:** I am using 'qr-image' for converting text to qr code.